# Does the C++11 standard guarantee identical random numbers for the same seed across implementations?

Tags: c++, random, c++11, standards

For example if I instantiate a `std::mt19937` with the exact same seed and parameters under GCC and under MSVC, should I get the same sequence of random numbers? If so I assume this property would hold for mersenne_twister_engine in general since mt19937 is just one with specific parameters. This is not true for `rand()` in C. It looks like the standard documents the transformations applied in terms of specific code, so I suspect it should always be the same, but the devil is in the details...

Comment: Different implementations of `rand` use different constants so they're never going to match. Wikipedia contains a handy list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use

Comment: @MarkRansom: Different implementations are allowed to use totally different algorithms for rand(), constants aside.

Comment: "Allowed to use", sure. In practice they all seem to be the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the new random number engines, yes, for the same seed and parameters you'll get the same sequence of values on all platforms. For `rand()`, no. You also don't have that guarantee with random number distributions, even when they are fed the same sequence of input values.

Comment: Also the distributions are not guaranteed to produce the same values, so combining an engine with a distribution will not give identical results across platforms.

Comment: C standard, 7.22.2.2/2 "The srand function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to rand. If srand is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If rand is called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1." How is that not a guarantee?

Comment: Also, for C++, my understanding is that operator== on two generators, adaptors or distributions will be true iff they will generate the same infinite sequences, so it is possible to obtain a guarantee if one exists.

Comment: Simple answer I assume is correct, but is there a convenient cite in the standard for this to make it more complete?

Comment: @rici - each implementation's version of `rand()` is required to generate the same sequence given the same seed, but there is no requirement that different implementations generate the same sequence.

Comment: @JosephGarvin - the requirement is distributed: each engine describes the algorithm that it uses, and, for a particular set of parameters, gives the 10,000th value (handy for checking that the implementation is correct).

Comment: pete, ah, true, the algorithm is not defined. @JosephGarvin, the Mersenne twister algorithm (and some other pseudo-random algorithms) are defined in the C++ standard in some detail, in section 26.5.3 (26.5.3.2 for Mersenne twister).