# Is the <random> library in c++11 portable?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

Is the  library in c++11 portable?  I have avoided rand() because I heard it wasn't portable.

Answer (score 17):

How do you define "portable"?

If by "portable", you mean "will produce binary identical sequences of random numbers given the same input", then yes, `rand` isn't portable. And yes, the [C++ random generators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) are portable (most of them. Not `std::default_random_engine` or [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device)), because they implement *specific* algorithms. `rand` is allowed to be anything, as long as it's not entirely unlike a random number generator.

That being said, as @PeteBecker pointed out, the distributions themselves are not so well-defined. So while `std::mt19937` will produce the same sequence of values for a given seed, different [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)s can give different values for the same input sequence and range.

Of course, if you need consistency, you can always define your own distribution.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant by portable.

Comment: You can find the rationale for the distributions being implementation defined in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24554535/1708801).

Answer (score 7):

The random number engines described in `<random>` have explicit requirements for their algorithms to ensure portability. The distributions do not.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: The C++ standard is the reference for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate "identical sequences of random numbers given the same input" (from @Nicol Bolas) with [std::mt19937 (Mersenne Twister)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/) for example. You definitely couldn't do that with `rand()` which was quite annoying.

Related questions:

- [Does the C++11 standard guarantee identical random numbers for the same seed across implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13589215/341970)
- [Consistent pseudo-random numbers across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/922358/341970)