# stl random distributions and portability

Tags: c++, c++11, random, stl, cross-platform

Why is it that the result of standard distributions isn't mandated to be consistent across implementations? The result of pseudo random number generators **is** on the other hand mandated to be identical.

For example, the following will almost certainly print something different for every different standard library implementation.

```
std::mt19937 random {100};
std::normal_distribution<> dist;

std::cout << dist(random);
```

Say I want to do procedural generation and would like identical starting seeds to result in identical results across platforms and compilers. I can't do it with the stl. I have to "regress" to using boost. Why isn't this a defect?

Comment: This isn't intended to be an answer, it's just something to think about . For many distributions, there are multiple ways to get the desired values. A normal distribution can use the box-muller transform, or a (recursive or taylor expansion) error function. Both of these use functions use other functions (such as cosine, sine, logarithm, error function, integrals, square root...). It's hard to say which method is best (time vs. precision), and which can be best optimized. Maybe in C++14 when people become more familiar with these distributions and implementations, a standard will be enforced.

Comment: Oh, and even the box-muller transform has different (polar, cartesian) implementations. Tons of ways for tons of fun?

Comment: @user2899162 you actually have the rationale correct, I quote the proposal in my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a defect, it is by design. The rationale for this can be found in [A Proposal to Add an Extensible Random Number Facility to the Standard Library (N1398)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1398.html) which says (*emphasis mine*):

> On the other hand, the specifications for the distributions only
>   define the statistical result, not the precise algorithm to use. This
>   is different from engines, because for distribution algorithms,
>   rigorous proofs of their correctness are available, usually under the
>   precondition that the input random numbers are (truely) uniformly
>   distributed. For example, **there are at least a handful of algorithms
>   known to produce normally distributed random numbers** from uniformly
>   distributed ones. **Which one of these is most efficient depends on at
>   least the relative execution speeds for various transcendental
>   functions, cache and branch prediction behaviour of the CPU, and
>   desired memory use**. This proposal therefore leaves the choice of the
>   algorithm to the implementation. It **follows that output sequences for
>   the distributions will not be identical across implementations**. It is
>   expected that implementations will carefully choose the algorithms for
>   distributions up front, since it is certainly surprising to customers
>   if some distribution produces different numbers from one
>   implementation version to the next.

This point is reiterated in the implementation defined section which says:

> The algorithms how to produce the various distributions are specified
>   as implementation-defined, because there is a vast variety of
>   algorithms known for each distribution. Each has a different trade-off
>   in terms of speed, adaptation to recent computer architectures, and
>   memory use. The implementation is required to document its choice so
>   that the user can judge whether it is acceptable quality-wise.

Comment: lovely; so if consistency across implementations is important one has to go the route of non-standard libraries.

Thanks for the relevant excerpt from the proposal.

Comment: @Brandon that is all I could find, so it does look like it. You can always bring this up on [ISO C++ Standard - Discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/std-discussion) and see if there is some room for changes.

Comment: not a bad idea. Something like a choice between fast and stable would be nice; not unlike what is done in <cstdint> (though a bit messy). Thanks again.