# Mersenne Twister Reproducibility across Compilers

Tags: c++, random, std

I'm generating a sequence of random numbers with std::mt19937_64. I've noticed that, when run with GCC and Clang on the same platform with the same seed, I obtain a different sequence. I've run the program through Valgrind and found no uninitialized memory.

Is there any guarantee to reproducibility across compilers or across platforms with std::mt19937_64?

Edit: Running with std::normal_distribution

Comment: If you need cross-compiler guaranteed compatibility you can use [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random.html).

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit naive here, but arguably if they are using the same algorithm and same parameters, shouldn't they reproduce the same sequence?

Comment: Since you are using normal distribution see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24554535/1708801) basically the answer is no but the underlying engines should be consistent looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The numbers that engines generate are guaranteed to be reproducible across implementations, but the distributions are not. (source: [rand() considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)).

The N3337 standard draft says this about `normal_distribution` (26.5.8.5.1):

> A normal_distribution random number distribution produces random numbers x distributed according to the probability density function
>
> [image]
>
> The distribution parameters µ and σ are also known as this distribution’s mean and standard deviation

And... that's it. It doesn't specify the order of the generated numbers, nor algorithm, nor example outputs.

The standard is very elaborate about `mersenne_twister_engine` (26.5.3.2), it specifies the state transition function, initial seeding algorithm and so on.

Comment: Is this caused by a difference in how the functions handle seeding?

Comment: The equation is wrong. I think you picked the wrong link.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I doubt so. The standard is *very* elaborate on how seeding is supposed to be working.

Comment: @rubenvb You're right. It's my mistake, I accidentally posted `gamma_distribution` instead. I'll fix it right away.